# How to CAST field from JSON column with Laravel Eloquent(POSTGRESQL)?

Tags: json, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

How I can change type of field in Json column `column->field->value` If type is string I have to change it on INT.

Comment: Maybe [Laravel attribute-casting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)?

Comment: @mare96 is it possible to pass there field from JSON? Because It does not work right

Answer (score 0):

There are Multi Solution For That
1- Faster One Is

```
$myfield->value = "ASDASDASD";
$myfield->value2 = 30;
$myfield->value3= true;
$myFieldEncoded= json_encode($myfield);
```

Then In Your Model Whatever Name Is Assume It `Blablabla`

```
$newData= new Blablabla;
$newData->field=$myFieldEncoded;
$newData->save();
```